# Getting a collection that does not contain elements of another collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a table of subjects, a table of posts, and a table of areas.

I am getting all the subjects for a specific area where its related posts have a status of 'Approved'. I wish to get another collection which is all subjects except those in the first collection.

I am getting the first collection like this:

```
$A = Subject::where('area_id', '=', $area->id)
        ->whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 'Approved');
        })
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

I wish to get a second collection which is all subjects for the same area, except those in the first collection. So far I have something like this:

```
$B = Subject::where('area_id', '=', $area->id)
        // some clause removing all subjects in A
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Did you try the oppposite ? `->where('status', '!=',  'Approved');` Where status IS NOT Approved

Comment: I tried this. The issue was that subjects can have multiple posts - some of which are approved and some rejected. If a subject had some approved posts and some rejected posts, then it would appear in both collection A and B.

Comment: a query that tests where the amount of approved posts is null would do the trick

Comment: Ok. Something dirty here. Assuming you dont have  too many records. All subjects in A, put their id in an array. Then in B, skip those IDs like this `->whereNotIn('id', $array_of_A_ids)`. Not the best solution though.

Comment: Alternatively, in B, replace `whereHas` by `whereDoesntHave` and see how it goes.